# Vue.js convert svg $ref element to dataURL

Tags: svg, vuejs2, vue-cli, data-uri

In vue.js I am trying to convert an svg element to a dataURL using the npm package [svg-to-dataurl](https://www.npmjs.com/package/svg-to-dataurl)

I am using $refs to get the element,

```
<svg ref="referenceSVG" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                        <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
                </svg>
```

I click a button which calls a method which gets the referenced element.

```
refSVG(){
        this.svgStr = this.$refs.referenceSVG
        ......
    }
```

Next I log this variable, which is of type string,

```
console.log(this.svgStr);//is an object
```

[image]

If I pass this.svgStr to the function svgToDataUrl(this.svgStr) the dataURL is not created correctly and gives,

[image]

If on the other hand, I directly pass in the element as a string like this,

```
this.dataUrl = svgToDataURL('<svg ref="referenceSVG" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" /></svg>')
```

This gives a dataURL which can be used,

```
data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg%20ref%3D%22referenceSVG%22%20version%3D%221.1%22%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%3E%3Ccircle%20cx%3D%2250%22%20cy%3D%2250%22%20r%3D%2240%22%20stroke%3D%22black%22%20stroke-width%3D%223%22%20fill%3D%22red%22%20%2F%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E
```

So it seems that the origin svgStr needs to be converted to a string. To do this I used,

```
this.toString = this.svgStr.toString()
```

and logged it, which gives,

```
[object SVGSVGElement]
```

Which is not the full element I'd expect and so no use in the svgToDataUrl().

How can I get the element into the svgToDataUrl() function for conversion to a dataURL?

Also I am not sure if I should be talking about a dataUri or dataUrl?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Your variable is not of type string but of type Object. Therefore if you call `toString()` on it it'll return the string representation of that object not the SVG content you're looking for.

You can access the HTML representation of a ref node though simply through its `outerHTML` property:

```
this.svgStr = this.$refs.referenceSVG.outerHTML
```

Comment: Wonderful, that's it. Thank you so much for this answer. I knew there was an innerHTML but not that there is an outerHTML. Works perfectly.